# Proftpd - hide all subdirectories

Tags: proftpd

I have a proftpd server setup working. Only one user, have locked them to the users directory.

How can I hide all subdirectories, so that when the user logs in they can only read and write to files within the login directory.

I thought it has something to do with:

`<Directory ~/>`

`HideNoAccess on`

And `<Limit DIR>`

This isn't from a security point of view, but an aesthetics view for the application I require.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

`<Directory ~/>
  HideFiles !(\.txt)$
  </Directory>`

Hides all files and folders except file with file extension .txt